# How to do sub-queries containing group by in Azure Cosmos DB for NoSQL

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to write a Azure Cosmos DB for NoSQL sub-query to get the documents with only the highest version. Consider the following data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "da640c23-4ba6-4f43-b140-b68ce4831cc3_1_0ff335a4-a8d4-4229-b897-5ed21f4bb6b7",
        "docId": "0ff335a4-a8d4-4229-b897-5ed21f4bb6b7",
        "pk": "da640c23-4ba6-4f43-b140-b68ce4831cc3_dril-prog",
        "name": "24/9-CP3-CX Y1H RevB0 [Tri-Lat MB] & 24/9-CP3-CX Y2H RevB0"
        "version": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "da640c23-4ba6-4f43-b140-b68ce4831cc3_2_0ff335a4-a8d4-4229-b897-5ed21f4bb6b7",
        "docId": "0ff335a4-a8d4-4229-b897-5ed21f4bb6b7",
        "pk": "da640c23-4ba6-4f43-b140-b68ce4831cc3_dril-prog",
        "name": "24/9-CP3-CX Y1H RevB0 [Tri-Lat MB] & 24/9-CP3-CX Y2H RevB0",
        "version": 2
    }
]
```

From here I need to return the second document with `id: "da640c23-4ba6-4f43-b140-b68ce4831cc3_2_0ff335a4-a8d4-4229-b897-5ed21f4bb6b7"` as it has the highest version (i.e. 2).

So far I have tried this queries, but no luck!

```
SELECT
    VALUE c
FROM
    c
JOIN 
    d IN (SELECT d.docId, Max(d.version) version FROM d GROUP BY d.docId)
WHERE
    c.version = d.version and c.docId = d.docId

SELECT VALUE c
FROM c
JOIN (
    SELECT c.docId, Max(c.version) AS maxVersion
    FROM c
    GROUP BY c.docId
) maxVersions
ON c.docId = maxVersions.docId AND c.version = maxVersions.maxVersion
```

Comment: The only joins you can do are self-joins; you can not do joins across different documents or different containers. That would likely explain the issue with your two queries.